# Many small and cheap linear actuators

Tags: motor, solenoid, actuator, piezoelectricity

Me and my friends are trying to build a linear actuator matrix. It's supposed to be a grid of pins that go up and down at reasonably fast speed (more than 1cm/s, the faster the better). Problem is, these things cost money and we haven't found something cheap enough. We have about $300 to spare, and would like to have ideally 1000 of them, but we can make do with about 300 (again, the more the better, and even better if we save some money).
We haven't found a cheap enough linear actuator that is small enough for our needs (2mm to 10mm diameter, the closer to 2mm the better) and we would like your help.

EDIT: To all your questions:
I'm building a tactile electronic display (which will look like a bed of nails) that people are supposed to touch.
I'm not sure how force the pins should withstand, but they are not going to be pushed, only touched by blind people, I presume it's less than 100N but I also think it is way less, I just don't have an accurate number.
As for the length I need the actuator to travel, about 5 to 15 millimeters.
To the guy who asked if the pins need to be either up or down or at different positions: There is a small preference towards intermediate positions (no specific number of positions required) but if the price doesn't allow it, we'll make do with up-down.

Comment: How far does each actuator need to travel? How much force do they need to produce? Are you building some sort of [haptic (touchable) interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haptic_technology)? Piezoelectric "squiggle" motors are that small and that fast, but I don't think you can get them for $0.30 - $1.00 each.

Comment: You can get small vibration motors in that price range.

Comment: Do the pins only need to be either up or down, or do you need intermediate positions? If so, how many steps and what spacing? Is this like a bed-of-nails? Do you need many/all actuators to be move simultaneously, or could you set the position of each of them one at a time?

Comment: Muscle wire, with a lever to move the pin? Small $3 servos from eBay are probably the cheapest actuator though.

Comment: @DaveTweed I know, I've seen squiggle motors and they seem great, maybe there is a way to get 1000 of them at once and get a discount you know of? (Also: see my edit)

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen I've seen several vibration motors, but I don't know how they can be beneficial for my need, they just vibrate, I need the pins to go up and down. Could you elaborate please?

Comment: @bigjosh See my edit. What do you mean about the part of whether I need actuators to move simultaneously or not? Are you asking about power consumption? Because that wouldn't matter to me. If you meant something else, please explain. Thanks :)

Comment: @tomnexus That muscle wire is interesting, but from this video: https://youtu.be/YR5lf4btWfw It seems pretty slow, can you make it faster? Could you elaborate? Thanks.

Comment: @shoham two ways: 1) increase the lever ratio, so the final part moves faster. Only helps if the force required is very small. 2) use a control loop to heat it up more quickly, providing a lot of power while it's cold. And perhaps a fan to speed up the cooling.

Answer (score 2):

Consider building your own tiny solenoids. I think this would make it possible to reach your functional and cost goals.

Your bed of nails would be made from an array of actual iron nails. Each nail would hang inside of a tubular coil with the nail head flush with the top of the coil and the bottom of the nail would protrude down beyond the bottom of the coil. When the coil was energized, it would pull the nail up into the coil and push the head up above the top of the coil.

[image]

To build each solenoid, I would start with a plastic rod that was slightly thicker than your nail shaft. I wind [very thin magnet wire](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0082CUQEI) around the rod using an electric drill, then solidify the coil using nail polish or lacquer or glue. Once hardened, slide the finished coil off the rod. Repeat 1,000 times.

You would need to experiment to find the optimal number of turns, wire thickness, and coil length for your application.

Attach a suitable flyback diode across the two leads of each coil, then wire the coils in a matrix so that you have one lead for each row and one for each column coming out of the matrix.

You can now drive this coil matrix by scanning across the rows and columns at high speed. You might want to use [high current shift registers](https://www.adafruit.com/products/457) to make it easier to interface to something like an Arduino.

It will take a lot of work, but I think you could something working your limited budget. Winding the coils actually gets fun after the first 20 or so - then less fun after the 100th... :)

This is just an overview of the strategy. Feel free to ask for details if you actually try to do it!

Comment: If you have more money than time, you can get some [surplus solenoids for $2.50 each](http://www.allelectronics.com/make-a-store/item/sol-102/miniature-12vdc-push-type-solenoid/1.html) that should work well.

Comment: It's interesting, I'll consult my friends to see if they're up for the job.

Answer (score 1):

[Here is a similar device, using 30x30 pins.](http://tangible.media.mit.edu/project/inform/)

[From the paper describing the device](http://tmg-trackr.media.mit.edu/publishedmedia/Papers/527-inFORM%20Dynamic%20Physical%20Affordances/Published/PDF):

> The  system  uses  **30 x 30**  motorized  white  polystyrene  pins,
>   in a **381 x 381 mm** area.   The pins have a 9.525 mm² footprint,
>   with 3.175 mm inter-pin spacing, and can extend up to 100 mm from the
>   surface.   **Push-Pull rods are used to link each pin with an
>   actuator, to enable a dense pin arrangement independent of actuator
>   size,**  giving the system a height of 1100 mm.  The linkage, a nylon
>   rod inside a plastic housing (Sullivan Gold-N-Rods), transmits
>   bi-directional force from a motorized slide potentiometer (ALPS
>   RSA0N11M9A07), through a bend.

I think the most important thing is that they make the size of the display independent from the size of the actuators by connecting each pin and its actuator with a rod. This gives more freedom of choice when looking for actuators.

I agree with @tomnexus that small servos are probably your cheapest option. But even considering a reduced price due to bulk ordering them, I doubt that you can build the device with your budget.

You have to keep in mind that you need wiring and electronics to control all these servos, too.
I can tell from experience that these cheap servos are cheap for a reason. They cannot take a lot of load.
If the desired user experience is not hearing plastic gears break, you probably want to go for a different solution.

I think that you have to either reduce the number of pins or raise your budget.

I highly recommend building a prototype of say 4x4 (or even less) pins.